# PHP: CodeIgniter; Managing two db connections; variable database parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i’m starting to code in CI and i have some problems with the following matter: I need a controller that will return a list of databases from a given server-login-pass and the tables in each database.

Reading the user guide i’ve found everything i need, but still i have trouble managing to make this work. I believe i cant rely on the database.php config (multiple groups) since my controler has to accept any given server-login-pass.

Going straight to the point, i’ve tried this basic code and many variants without luck ;

```
$db1 = $this->load->database('mysql://flux:foo@localhost');
$db2 = $this->load->database('mysql://flux:foo@localhost/mydb');

$this->load->dbutil();

$db_list = $db1->list_databases();
print_r($db_list);

$db_tables = $db2->db->list_tables();
print_r($db_tables);
```

Also i'm not sure about:

```
$this->load->dbutil();
```

The user guide states:

```
Important:  In order to initialize the Utility class, your database driver must 
already be running, since the utilities class relies on it.
```

So if for example i had two simultaneous databases loaded, both with diferent drivers, how would i change $this->load->dbutil(); to load in the one id want?

Comment: have you tried `$db1->load->dbutil();` ?

Comment: Found detailed help in: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/202659/

Comment: yep, mark your question as answered please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found detailed help in: [www.codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/202659](http://www.codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/202659)

Comment: I can't see your link. can you show me the right link? thanks